# Creating a Restaurant Menu should I use a has_many through or habtm association?

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, database-design

I am attempting to create a Restaurant project and design the database for the menu. While creating the database schema, I seem to keep spinning my wheels on how to implement the correct associations among the following models `MenuItem, Menu, and a Menu Section`. Every time I go through the `has_many :through`, and `has_and_belongs_to_many`, I can see the benefits of both but then when I implement them I get confused. Additionally, I have the confusion of a `self join` to the mix which further throws me off.

I think that I am over engineering but some input into the database schema would be helpful. More specifically, which association should I use for the following scenario in your opinion?

So far I have three classes/tables `Restaurant, Menu, and MenuItem` and the scenario I have crafted:

```
class Restaurant
  has_many :menus  (#Desert, Drinks, Dinner, Lunch, etc.)
end

class Menu
  has_many :sections, class_name: "Menu", foreign_key: "sections_id"
  belongs_to :section, class_name: "Menu"

  has_many :menu_items, through: :sections

  belongs_to :restaurant
end

## Context for the Menu and Sections
If I had a drinks menu with the following sections, Non Alcoholic, 
Spirits, Wine, etc. These 'sections' are essentially menus with 
their own menu items. This is why I put a self join on the Menu 
class. Maybe Im mistaken.


 class MenuItem
   belongs_to :section, class_name: "Menu"
   belongs_to :menu
 end 

 ####
 The menu item for example of 'Yellow Tail Merlot' belongs to the 
 section "Wine" under the menu of "Drinks". This is precisely where
 I am getting thrown off. I get the feeling that I'm making this 
 too complicated but when I say it out loud to myself it makes 
 perfect sense.
```

Ok so now here is version 2 with the habtm:

```
class Restaurant
  has_many :menus  (#Desert, Drinks, Dinner, Lunch, etc.)
end

class Menu
   has_and_belongs_to_many :menu_items
end


 class MenuItem
  has_and_belongs_to_many :menus
  has_and_belongs_to_many :sections, class_name: "Menu"
 end
```

As you can see the above code in version 2 gets hairy. In fact, I don't even know if the sections part of has_and_belongs_to_many is possible. Anyways, this is my rationale taken from the Rails Associations docs.

> A has_and_belongs_to_many association creates a direct many-to-many connection with another model, with no intervening model. For example, if your application includes menus and menu items, with each menu having many menu items and each menu item appearing in many menus, you could declare the models this way.

The quote is from the rails docs but I switched assemblies and parts with menus and menu items. Reading it that way makes complete sense. So now I ask, what do you guys think? Which would be better to use? Thank you.

Comment: AFAIK HABTM was deprecated in Rails 4, possibly earlier. Ii've always felt has_many through: was a much cleaner option

Comment: Self joins are not really relevant here. An example of where thats applicable is where you have a users table where employees join managers (which are also records on the users table) on `users.manager_id`. What you are building is a hierarchy so its definatly the wrong tool for the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> should I use a has_many through or habtm association?

They both can be used to create similar many to many associations. The key difference is that `has_and_belongs_to_many` does not use a model for the join entities. While this sounds simple and appealing it does have some huge cons:

- There is no practical way to add access additional columns on the join table. For example you want to add an "position" column to sort the items - you´re out of luck with `has_and_belongs_to_many`.
- There is no way to directly query the join table.

So `has_and_belongs_to_many` is great for those zero complexity cases and not very good in real life. For everything else there is `has_many through:`.

```
class Restaurant
  has_many :menus
  has_many :menu_sections, through: :menus
  has_many :menu_items, through: :menu_sections
end

class Menu
  belongs_to :restaurant
  has_many :menu_sections
  has_many :menu_items, through: :menu_sections
end

class MenuSection
  belongs_to :menu
  has_one :restaurant, through: :menu
  has_many :menu_items
end

class MenuItem
  belongs_to :menu_section
  has_one :menu, through: :menu_section
  has_one :restaurant, through: :menu
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use `belongs_to` and instead of using a self join on the Menu table, create a new class/table called `Section`.

Updated would be:

```rb
class Restaurant
  has_many :menus
end

class Menu
  has_many :menu_items
  has_many :sections

  belongs_to :restaurant
end

class Section 
  belongs_to :menu
  has_many :menu_items
end


class MenuItem
  belongs_to :menu
  belongs_to :section
end
```

The sections you describe are more categories, e.g. Wine is an alcoholic drink, Wine is the menu item and 'alcoholic drink' is the category. You could even go one step further and have Wine associated with two sections, 'alcoholic' and 'drink'.